# JWT Cookie now appearing under application tab, but is being sent in request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am sending back a jwt token to an authorized user using this code in express:

I am using a cookie-parser module.

```
module.exports.getUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('i am in getuser');
  const { SIT } = req.query;
  const { oid } = res.locals.tokenPayload;

  await getUserById({ params: { userId: oid } }, SIT)
    .then((user) => {
      const token = createToken(oid);
      res.cookie('jwt', token, {httpOnly: true, maxAge: 24 * 1000 * 1000});
      res.status(200).send(user);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};
```

And this is the request:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4kiu.png)

You can clearly see that the set-cookie property is set with a jwt token.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHAGA.png)

And the above image here is the cookies tab in the network request.

This is the view under application tab -> localhost -> Cookeis:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKcaw.png)

Why is the jwt token not visible in there?

I tried to remove the http only property as i read somewhere that it could help.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: it's a cross origin request, right? Did you set the appropriate `credentials` flag in the request so that cross origin cookies will be accepted? since you haven't shown the request code, it's hard to tell, but that's a very common mistake

Comment: @JaromandaX i did try to set the credentials flag but i think i did it in the wrong place. The frontend triggers this endpoint which creates the token after a user has been authenticated. Is it the call that is made from Frontend ' Login ' request that should have this flag?

Comment: yes, the frontend calls need the credentials flag

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set a JWT in a cookie using Node.js:

```
  let jwt = 'aaaaaa.bbbbbbbb.ccccccc';
  let cookieArray = [];
  cookieArray.push(`someKey=someValue`);
  cookieArray.push(`token=${jwt}; HttpOnly`);
  response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookieArray);
```

The `HttpOnly` property makes cookie values unreadable to client-side JavaScript, which is regarded as a security feature. So this property is commonly used.

Comment: This is not the question that i asked.

Comment: There are many JavaScript / Node.js experts on this forum who can help you if you could clarify your specific question.